# Horizontal Overflow Scroll on Squarespace - Eliminate White Space?

Tags: css, squarespace

Here's my website:

[www.lukassuarez.com](http://www.lukassuarez.com)

I use the code below on my gallery to create a horizontal scroll. The only problem is there is a lot of white space at the very end.

Simple question - how do I delete the white space?

```css
<style>
   .sqs-gallery {
     overflow: scroll;
   }
   body {
     background-image: none;
   }
   .sqs-gallery-design-strip-slide {
     padding-left: 3px;
     padding-right: 3px;
   }
 </style>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $( window ).load(function() {
     w = $(".sqs-wrapper").width();
     $(".sqs-wrapper").width(w/2);
   })
 </script>
```

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools to inspect the page. You can see your `div` with ID `canvas` has 20px padding, there is an empty footer with `margin-top: 50px`, and your `seciton` with ID `page` has 50px padding top and bottom. Simple answer to your simple question: remove the HTML content that is causing the white spaces. Or fill it.

Comment: How do I remove the HTML comment?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Where did you get the HTML content? How did you add it to the site?

Comment: By HTML content, do you mean the pictures? Or do you mean the scrolling feature? The scrolling feature is imbedded via css that Squarespace allows someone to input. The pictures are added naturally through Squarespace's style editor. I used my web tools to inspect the page, but I'm not sure what I'm looking for, and also, the only way to edit my webpage is through Squarespace (again, I can use css).

Answer (score 0):

If you can only edit the CSS, you can hide the elements you are not using and set lower padding and margin to other elements.

You can easily see which elements take up the white space by using your browser's developer tools and inspecting the undesired white area.

In your case, you can see a footer with no content, only empty HTML tags with `min-height: 34px;`. You can also see `div` element with ID 'page' with `padding: 50px 0;` and `div` with ID 'canvas' with `padding: 20px;`

Example CSS:

```
#footerBlock {
    // Remove min-height
    min-height: 0;
}

#page {
    // Lower bottom padding
    padding: 50px 0 20px;
}
```

Other possibilities are to fill the footer with content or remove the footer entirely, if you have access to HTML files.

Comment: Hm, are we talking about the same thing? You seem to be talking about no content in the footer area - that is intentional. Go back to my page, click on the "Archives" section, and look through the gallery - I refer to the white space that is to the RIGHT, as your HORIZONTALLY scroll.

Comment: Oh. Please edit the link in your question to point directly to https://www.lukassuarez.com/#/archives-1/ then. The div element with class `sqs-wrapper` has width set in its style. There is not much you can do about it in CSS. I'm guessing it is a calculated value from the images width. It even changes when you change your browser width. However the width is not calculated correctly. I suggest you use some sort of an image slider instead of a huge div with overflow.